# Grass plugin not working

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am trying to work with GRASS in QGIS 3.10.1. I went to "Manage and Install Plugins", searched for it, and checked the box for GRASS 7. That brought up an error message that says "Grass was not found in '/use/local/opt/osgeo-grass/grass-base' - I can't see if the error message says more, because it is timed and disappears within a couple of seconds.

After that message, I go to Plugins > Grass and all of the options to open a new mapset, etc. are greyed out. When I got to Grass Options > General the default location is selected (/use/local/opt/osgeo-grass/grass-base) and underneath it says "Currently selected location is not valid".

I downloaded a new version of GRASS and installed it on my Mac as I would any other program (dragged it to the Applications folder), but I don't know if that was necessary or what to do next, and I have not been able to find documentation that addresses this issue.

Comment: Hi, is `/use/local/opt/osgeo-grass/grass-base` really correct? Usually `/usr/...` would be expected (note: `use` --> `usr`).

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo - it was /usr/...